# Remove genesis_404 hook from genesis_loop

Tags: hooks, actions, genesis-theme-framework

I am using the genesis theme and I want to make a custom 404 page. For that, I wish to remove the default 404 hook and implement my own. In my plugins functions.php I added my action:

```
add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_customizations_404' );
```

And in the function I added the remove:

```
function genesis_customizations_404() {
   echo 'test';
   remove_action('genesis_loop', 'genesis_404');
}
```

But this is not working. I also tried moving the `remove_action()` to my functions.php file, without succes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem:

For some reason, the `add_action()` and `remove_action()` had to be contained inside another action, `genesis_meta`:

```
add_action( 'genesis_meta', function () {
    if (is_404()) {
        remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_404' );
        add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_customizations_404' );
    }
}, 11);
```